# .ogg video not playing in firefox

Tags: html, ogg, html5-video

We're just getting started with html5 video, and cannot seem to get `.ogg` files to play in Firefox, any tips? Here is the source we are using:

```
<video width="640" height="360" poster="http://video.thewebreel.com/episode_001/episode_001.jpg" controls autoplay autobuffer>
  <source src="http://video.thewebreel.com/episode_001/episode_001.ogg" type="video/ogg" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'/>
  <source src="http://video.thewebreel.com/episode_001/episode_001.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

The live example can be seen here:

```
http://thewebreel.com/2010/05/02/episode-1.html
```

However we are totally baffled, everything seems exactly right.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643447/html5-video-mp4-and-ogv-problems-in-safari-and-firefox-but-chrome-is-all-good/2644341

Comment: Why do you have two type attributes on the first source?

Comment: copy/paste error, that wasn't the issue it seems, but thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I uploaded your .ogg to my server suspecting it was a server issue and it's working fine on my server

I'm guessing it's because your web server is replying with

```
Content-type: binary/octet-stream
```

Try adding the mime types to nginx...

Open up the Nginx mime type configuration file, eg: /etc/nginx/mime.types

Add these lines after the last video mime type

```
video/ogg                             ogm;
video/ogg                             ogv;
video/ogg                             ogg;
```

Comment: I'm using Amazon S3, do you think I should use: `video/ogg` or `application/ogg` for some reason their docs say `application/ogg` I'm not really clear, thanks again!

Comment: i'd try application/ogg since that's what their docs say.  my server replies with that and it works.

Comment: application/ogg should work (and used to be recommended), but technically nowadays you should use video/ogg.

http://blog.gingertech.net/2008/09/05/new-ogg-mime-types-ratified/

Comment: I’d also add audio/ogg mime-type for the .oga extension for good measure. :)

Answer (score 2):

In one of the links mentioned, the correct way to play ogg files is..

```
<audio preload="auto" controls="controls">
  <source src="media/song.ogg" type="application/ogg">
</audio>
```

Thanks to the person who pointed it out here.
[HTML5 video (mp4 and ogv) problems in Safari and Firefox - but Chrome is all good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643447/html5-video-mp4-and-ogv-problems-in-safari-and-firefox-but-chrome-is-all-goo/2644341#2644341)

Answer (score 2):

The correct mime types to set on your server are

```
AddType audio/ogg .oga (audio oga file)
AddType video/ogg .ogv (video ogv file)
AddType application/ogg .ogg (for audio and video)
```

Sources:

- http://wiki.xiph.org/MIME_Types_and_File_Extensions
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Configuring_servers_for_Ogg_media

Answer (score 1):

Ogg videos play were playing on Firefox 3.6 but not 4.0.

Here's the solution:  video autobuffer controls preload="auto" instead of video controls preload="none"

This works in Firefox 3.6 and 4.0 and now MSIE 9!

Comment: lol, totally, html5 video support has a long way to go, its sad that the barriers are licensing, its resulting in a crappier experience for everyone.