# Firefox To Play Ogg

Tags: firefox, audio, ogg

I have an ogg/audio file converted from mp3 using Alt WAV MP3 Ogg Converter.
When I drag and drop the file in Firefox or in Google Chrome, the audio plays nicely.
But when a use the following code to place the file inside a page it only works on Chrome.

My code is simple as that:

```
<audio controls>  
     <source src="foo.ogg" type="audio/ogg">  
</audio>
```

Someone can tell me why?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756414/ogg-video-not-playing-in-firefox).
In my case I had to add MIME types to our nginx server.

Answer (score 0):

Because this works on IE:

```
<source src="foo.ogg" type="audio/mp3">`
```

And this works on Chrome, Mozilla, Safari, Opera

```
<source src="foo.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
```