# HTML5 video problem

Tags: video, html

i wonder what i'm doing wrong?

```
<video id="movie" width="320" height="240" preload controls>
  <source src="pr6.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
  <source src="pr6.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
  <source src="pr6.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />
</video>
```

this peace of code lies in my index.html. in the same directory i got all 3 videofiles (mp4, webm, ogv)

Somehow the video component shows up, however no video gets played. A big X shows up inside of the video component.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is that this is a duplicate of [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643447/html5-video-mp4-and-ogv-problems-in-safari-and-firefox-but-chrome-is-all-good/2644341). If so, the answer is: Make sure your server config has the following associations:

- .ogv: video/ogg
- .oga: audio/ogg
- .ogg: application/ogg
- .webm: video/webm
- .mp4: video/mp4

Comment: Ah this is probably it. I had this issue too and couldn't get Apache to recognise .ogv files. Change the extension to .ogg (as this is usually set up by default) and see if that works?

Comment: where do i make these changes for tomcat?

Answer (score 1):

On which browser? IE for example doesn't support the video element at all.
Also, the course element is a void element and as such shouldn't have an end tag.
I've also noticed a bug in Firefox where the Ogg file has to be the first resource otherwise it doesn't work. This may have been fixed in 3.6.3 though.

Comment: i'm using firefox 3.6 and it's working here http://diveintohtml5.org/video.html (scroll to the bottom), i'm using the exact same code and i can't seem to get it working in firefox! however it's working in chrome and safari. only firefox wont support it. MOREOVER i've absolutely no idea how i can position this video with css. #movie wont work!

Comment: Are you using the html5 doctype too?

Comment: Ian, the doctype has nothing to do with this.

Comment: no! i didn't use it! thank you, now I'm able to position the video via css. however firefox still doesn't support the video!

Answer (score 1):

Firefox 3.6 doesn't support WebM video format. To view HTML5 WebM videos you need to download a [nightly build of Firefox 4](http://nightly.mozilla.org/webm/)

For Ogv take care of frame rates and don't expect to show HD video. With a higher rate Firefox couldn't show my video, but when I reduce the frame rate and the quality, it works fine.