# Opera and HTML5 video

Tags: html, video, cross-browser, opera, ogg-theora

On my website, I have video in mp4 and ogv formats.
mp4 plays in webkit browsers.
ogv plays in Firefox, but don't want in Opera.

There is a trivial HTML:

```
<video poster="my_video.jpg" controls="controls">
    <source src="my_video.mov" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="my_video.ogv" type="video/ogg; codecs='theora, vorbis'" />
</video>
```

When i open up a page, i see video element with poster, but when i'm clicking play button, nothing happens. I don't see loading progress and everything still as is.
But Firefox plays it fine.

In Opera's network inspector, i see following HTTP Header for .ogv video file request:

> GET /my_video.ogv HTTP/1.1
>
> User-Agent: Opera/9.80 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6.7; U; ru) Presto/2.7.62 Version/11.01
>
> Accept: text/html, application/xml;q=0.9, application/xhtml+xml, image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, */*;q=0.1

"Accept" part is confusing me. Why it accepts these content types for video ?

Any ideas ?

Comment: Servers do not really pay attention to `Accept` only on content-negotiation, when the same URL can represent more resources and it chooses the best one to access.

Comment: To add to vbence's comment, the `Accept` header is probably not the problem. To my experience with `<video>`, there is probably some compatibility difficulty. Look up `.canPlayType`.

Comment: Can you play the file locally? - *Also consider using WebM and H.264 as your two fromats to get the maximum compatibility.*

Comment: Yes, i Opera plays the file locally.

Answer (score 1):

For Opera, you really only need to have [these two mime types](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/everything-you-need-to-know-about-html5-video-and-audio/) added to Apache or any server you would be using.

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType audio/ogg .oga
```

Is this [video](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aGullivers_travels1939.ogg) working for you? 
Do you have a link to the video you are trying to play?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out.

I has MIME types, listed in YAML file, that should be specified on Mongrel loading:

```
/usr/bin/mongrel_rails -m /path_to_mime_types.yml
```

I only has ".ogv: video/ogg" there. But, according to [HTML5 video problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964193/html5-video-problem), Opera needs more:

```
.ogv: video/ogg
.oga: audio/ogg
.ogg: application/ogg
.webm: video/webm
.mp4: video/mp4
```

When i added these types, Opera will play .ogv video.

Thanks.

Comment: Interesting. Why would `.oga: audio/ogg` influence how a `.ogv` file is served.

Comment: I've just added these types and Opera got it to play.

Comment: Check the response headers if you can. What content-type is the server sending?

Comment: content-type is "video/ogg" (checked with curl). I don't know, what the problem is about, but it, sure in server side (Rails), because local files are playing.