# Video tag in html

Tags: asp.net, html, video, html5-video

I am trying to play video with different browser

```
<video Controls>
      <source src="Videos/2.ogv" type="video/ogv">
      <source src="Videos/2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
```

but the `google chrome` plays the video but `firefox` doesn't play it. it shows an error that `perticuler MIME type is missing` after registering in IIS for `ogv extension` it still shows an error. is there any format that all browser support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content-type should be `video/ogg` not  `video/ogv`-

```
<source src="Videos/2.ogv" type="video/ogg">
```

Add these `MIME types` in your .htaccess file

Audio

```
AddType audio/aac .aac
AddType audio/mp4 .mp4 .m4a
AddType audio/mpeg .mp1 .mp2 .mp3 .mpg .mpeg
AddType audio/ogg .oga .ogg
AddType audio/wav .wav
AddType audio/webm .webm
```

Video

```
AddType video/mp4 .mp4 .m4v
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/webm .webm
```

[**HTML5 Audio & Video MIME Types**](http://voice.firefallpro.com/2012/03/html5-audio-video-mime-types.html)

Comment: sir it still don't work. i have made such changes 
      <video controls="controls">
      <source src="Videos/2.ogv" type="video/ogg">
      <source src="Videos/2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>

Comment: @Abhishekgupta You need to contact your webhost and get them to add .ogv - video/ogg as a valid MIME type (they should know what you mean) Same for MP4.

Comment: @Abhishekgupta check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964193/html5-video-problem

Comment: sir i have converted the file into .webm if i play the individual file. it plays into a firefox. but if i am integrating into my project it doesnt...<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <video controls="controls" tabindex="5">
     <source src="Videos/2.webm" type="video/webm">
      <source src="Videos/2.ogv" type="video/ogg">
      <source src="Videos/2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
     
      </video>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="View" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
the code is as follows

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the firefox maybe it dont support HTML 5

Comment: Sir i updated the firefox to version 15 but still doesn't play

Comment: Firefox was one of the first to support HTML5.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video try this. if it works your .ogg file is broken