# html5 video tag not displaying video, does ColdFusion make a difference?

Tags: html, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I'm on a server still running ColdFusion version 8.  I'm not sure if this is my problem though.

I have the following code that I can get to work in my computer on my desktop, using both Firefox and Chrome.  I access it as an html file directly using a file system url, i.e. file:///C:/.../test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
   <title>test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
     <p> Try w3Schools test video</p>
     <video width="320" height="240" controls>
         <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
         <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
         Your browser does not support the video tag.
     </video>
 </body>
 </html>
```

When I put this test.cfm or test.html page up on the Coldfusion 8 server, neither browser displays the video. The movie.mp4 and movie.ogv files are up on the server in the same directory as the test.cfm file.  In Firefox I get:

"No video with supported format and MIME type found."

In Chrome it shows the video controls but no video is present.

Is there something I need to enable on the server (it is a shared hosting account)?  Perhaps this is not particular to ColdFusion and I'm making another mistake (note this is my first attempt to use the video tags).

Thanks

P.S.  If I access it on my computer using Aptana's launch mechanism and running in:

127.0.0.1:8000/.../test.html

I get the same problem as running on the server.  The videos do not display.

Comment: The code that you have posted has nothing to do with ColdFusion.  In fact you should be able to rename that file from test.cfm to test.htm and take ColdFusion out of the loop.  My guess would be something with the web server config.  What are you using; IIS? Those file types, mp4 and ogv, may not be allowed.  Also check the [supported formats for each browser here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp). For example, IE does not support WebM or Ogg.

Comment: See these two similar posts: [HTML5 video problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964193/html5-video-problem) and [HTML5 video (mp4 and ogv) problems in Safari and Firefox - but Chrome is all good](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643447/html5-video-mp4-and-ogv-problems-in-safari-and-firefox-but-chrome-is-all-goo/2644341#2644341)

Comment: Thanks Miguel-F, that did it (mime types weren't supported on server, yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Courtesy of Miguel-F's guidance, the server was missing support for the .mp4 and .ogv mime types.  When the hosting company added those to the server, the videos displayed.