# Does HTML5 support .wmv and .mp4 files?

Tags: html, mp4, wmv

The videos are not showing up. Is this because they are not supported? They work fine if I go directly the the URL of the video I have uploaded to my server. .ogv file works, but .mp4 and .wmv does not. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help: [HTML5 video (mp4 and ogv) problems in Safari and Firefox - but Chrome is all good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643447/html5-video-mp4-and-ogv-problems-in-safari-and-firefox-but-chrome-is-all-good)

wmv is a Windows proprietary format and won't work.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on every browser.
http://w3schools.com/html5/html5_video.asp