# Video not displaying in Safari browser using HTML5

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I have used HTML5 for displaying a video. My code is

```
<video tabindex="0" autobuffer="" poster="" height="380" width="600">
    <source src="media/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="media/video.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="media/video.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    <img alt="Film Poster" src="" height="380" width="600">
</video>
```

But this is not displaying in safari browser...

What is the problem?

Comment: Do you have a demo page with this and your active video that we can see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the `.ogg` file extension to `.ogv` (both actual file and in the html sources)
Take a look at some of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643447/html5-video-mp4-and-ogv-problems-in-safari-and-firefox-but-chrome-is-all-goo)