# HTML5 Video not found

Tags: html, video

So the video and the html file are both in the same folder.

```
    <video width="320" height="240" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
      <source src="buyers.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
```

The video does not load and is not found. I do relative path (`../video/buyers.ogg`). Can someone please help me?

Comment: So do you use `buyers.ogg` or `/video/buyers.ogg`?  You're code says one thing but your relative path is different.

Comment: I use both and NEITHER work. And the html document and .ogg video are in the same folder. PROBLEM? YES

Comment: What browser and version are you using?

Comment: Opera, Firefox, Google Chrome and IE IN ALL cases they do not work.

Comment: I would assume that you are using the latest versions of these browsers but just for precautionary measures, [here is a link](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_video.asp) for information on which browsers and versions that support the `<video>` tag.  But something tells me there's an issue with the location of the video file (perhaps even the codec)...

Comment: The video is in the same folder as the html document. I can't stress it enough. The codecs are fine because I can watch other .mp4 or .ogg videos in all those browsers. No one seems to know why this happens.

Comment: Well maybe if someone actually answered a question I would accept it. I appreciate the help, but, I can't accept an answer unless it's been answered. How would I "hard-code" the location? You mean the exact location from C:/?

Comment: Understandable, and yes the exact location from  C:/.

Comment: Funny. It doesn't work, yet it works in VLC and Windows Media player. It's also funny how if I go online and watch an .ogg video, it works, but, when I do it locally it doesn't. Thanks Mike, you're pinpointing the problem here. It may be codecs. But the problem is, even if I upload it to my website, it still doesn't work.

Comment: You're very welcome.  I'm going to continue researching the problem and I'll let you know what I find sometime tomorrow.

Comment: At this point I would compare the codec of the viewable videos with your videos.  Heck, I would even try putting `<!DOCTYPE...>` at the beginning of your HTML file if you haven't done so.

Comment: There is a <!DOCTYPE HTML> at the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

Based on our discussion, here's something that may fix your problem.

If you don't have an [.htaccess](/questions/tagged/.htaccess) file, create one and add these lines to it:

---

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
```

For more information, go to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643447/html5-video-mp4-and-ogv-problems-in-safari-and-firefox-but-chrome-is-all-goo/2644341#2644341).

---

**UPDATE**:
Check out [this link](http://support.godaddy.com/groups/web-hosting/forum/topic/html-5-video-tag-problem/).  The poster sounds like he had the same problem as you are having currently.  Perhaps the addition of these tags will help.

```
<mimeMap fileExtension=".ogg" mimeType="video/ogg" />
<mimeMap fileExtension=".ogv" mimeType="video/ogg" />
```

Your site may not be hosted by GoDaddy, but it might help you pinpoint your problem.  Let me know if it works!

Comment: Thanks, but, the .htaccess file didn't do anything. Useful to have an .htaccess file regardless.

Comment: Except this time. It takes longer for it to load, and, then fail. Close, but, no cigar.

Comment: This is pissing me off. SERIOUSLY, WHY CAN NO ONE EXPLAIN WHY THE VIDEO DOESNT PLAY. I tried using HTML5 video player. It will play their video but not mine?? WTF

Comment: @ChrisCates Okay, one final suggestion... is your web page currently in the testing phase or is it up and running?  If it is up and running, you should check out the link that I posted in my answer.

Comment: There's a follow-up question (duplicate?) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267129/html5-video-not-working-locally-or-on-server-never.

Comment: @thirtydot Thank you for fixing my post with the funny quotes ;)  I have a strange tendency to put quotes around things that don't need quotes... and thank you for the update on the other question!

Answer (score 0):

The extension you have in your htaccess doesn't match what you are asking for (.ogv vs .ogg). But are you sure that the file itself isn't available to the browser?

Comment: The file is located in the same folder as the .html document.

Comment: Sure but can you access that file directly in your browser or do you get a 404 or other type of error?

Comment: I don't get any error, I can access it and download it. Or it just doesn't work. But the desired result is for it to be streamed in the web browser.

Comment: Well if you fixed the extension problem and that didn't help either than it must be the tag or something else mysterious. I would check all those.

Comment: lol nope, fixed everything, don't see it. Don't think I ever will (FML)

Answer (score 0):

Add an eventlistener for error to the video node.check the w3c spec on html5 video to make sense of what that event tells you (I'm on my iPad right now, else I'd give you more details....)

Also check the console for error messages and if your htaccess add type actually worked. Might be your provider disabled that. Which browsers did you test it in? Ie9 is very picky, chrome takes it all and firefox is kinda in between, like safari)

Last but not least, using ogv and webm is overkill. Decide for one of them. You only NEED mp4 and ONE of e others. Go to www.caniuse.com and search for "video" to understand why

Answer (score -1):

had the same problem i just downloaded a older version of firefox and it works now

Comment: This does not explain much :(