# How to play videos on my website?

Tags: php, html, video

I have a video website where users can upload videos. The problem is that the uploaded videos don't play.

I tried mp4, avi but they don't work.

```
<video id="myvideo">
<source scr="trial.mp4">
</video>
```

Videos are uploaded to the server but do not have playback controls.

Can anyone recommend some video players,format convert,etc.?

Comment: Does your browser support html5 (video)?

Comment: You should use [VideoJS](http://videojs.com/)

Comment: yeah i use google chrome

Comment: Is this video working: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_all ?

Comment: yeah it does.I mean,you guys have no problem when playing videos you upload?

Answer (score 0):

[JWPlayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player/) is a great video player, and the website has a lot of very useful (and well-written) advice for getting video to work on your website.

Comment: i do use videoJS <video id="myvideo" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls="controls" width="640" height="264" poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.jpg" preload="auto" data-setup="{}"> <source type="video/mp4" src="trial.mp4" /> </video>

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo:
you must replace "scr" by "src", in your code.

Comment: no it's src in the code(just made a mistake here)a test video from videoJS plays normally

Answer (score 0):

Edit: 
**"Videos are uploaded to the server but do not have playback controls."**

If you're using Video.js and you aren't getting any player controls appearing properly (assuming you're still using the code you specified in the reply to comments), it's most likely because you've not included the CSS file above the video.js include, as specified in the Videojs documentation

```
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

If that's not the issue, and videos aren't playing back at all (as you originally stated), then it may be potentially something else that's crossed my mind. Seeing as you're a Chrome user, if you right click on your video page, go to inspect element, then click the console tab.

If you've got anything to do with the wrong Mime type being sent, then information here may help:

[HTML5 video (mp4 and ogv) problems in Safari and Firefox - but Chrome is all good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643447/html5-video-mp4-and-ogv-problems-in-safari-and-firefox-but-chrome-is-all-goo)

Specifically [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7727768/2119914) reply

I'm not sure I can help anymore without further explanation / information.

---

Specify the type of video.

E.g.

```
<source scr="trial.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

Comment: I use videoJS and the type is specified

Comment: By the way i checked the network errors and here is the error message i received Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type video/mp4: