# Java servlet doesn't render mp4 in safari with html5 video tag

Tags: java, html, servlets, video, safari

The html5 video tag fails to load mp4 from servlet.

**My servlet code**

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Enumeration<String> enumn = request.getHeaderNames();
    while(enumn.hasMoreElements()){
        String hr = enumn.nextElement();
        System.out.println(hr + " - "+request.getHeader(hr));
    }       

    String fileName =  "test.mp4";
    String filePath =  "/Users/home/Downloads/test.mp4";

    String range = request.getHeader("range");
    File file = new File (filePath) ;
    long fileLength = file.length();        

    response.setContentType("video/mp4");
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    response.setHeader("Cache-control", "private");
    response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "fileDownload=true; path=/");
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);  
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""+ fileName+"\"");  

    response.setHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
    response.setHeader("Etag", "W/\"9767057-1323779115364\"");
    response.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");

    response.setBufferSize((int)fileLength + 200);
    response.setContentLength((int)fileLength);
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "video/mp4" );
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf( file.length()));

    BufferedInputStream  input = null ; 
    BufferedOutputStream output = null;
    try {

        input = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream(file) );
        output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
        byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)fileLength];
        for (int length = 0 ; (length = input.read(buffer)) > 0 ;) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        response.flushBuffer(); 
        System.out.println("buffer length : "+buffer.length);
        response.setHeader("Content-Range", "0-"+ Integer.valueOf(buffer.length-1));            
        System.out.println("=======================================================================");
        for(String hr : response.getHeaderNames()){
            System.out.println(hr + " - "+response.getHeader(hr));
        }

    }  catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (output != null) try { output.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
        if (input != null) try { input.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
    }
}
```

**Video Tag**

It is working fine in firefox and chrome. But safari is failing to load the video.

Comment: <video width="400" controls  >
   <source src="http://localhost:8080/TestVideo/RenderVideo?a2972" type="video/mp4">
 </video>

Comment: Take a look at this page: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643447/html5-video-mp4-and-ogv-problems-in-safari-and-firefox-but-chrome-is-all-goo

Comment: Hi Reidar, Thanks for response. I am using weblogic server. Also able to reproduce the issue in tomcat7.0. That page didn't help out.

Comment: If you post some more results (MIME - etc) and what you have tried it might be easier to help you