# HTML5 <video> tag not working in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, video

```
    <video  poster="https://res.cloudinary.com/deesul/image/upload/v1482128248/Up_ci3qna.jpg" autoplay="true" loop preload="auto" >
  <source src="https://res.cloudinary.com/deesul/video/upload/v1482630062/Up_1_ofz5ri.ogv" type="video/ogv">
 <source src="https://res.cloudinary.com/deesul/video/upload/v1482126175/Up_srxisl.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8.0, vorbis"'>     
  <source src="https://res.cloudinary.com/deesul/video/upload/v1482126174/Up_tle5de.mp4" type="video/mp4">     
</video>
```

this is not displaying the poster nor the video in firefox. Please help me resolve this issue on firefox.

Comment: OGV file format may have problem for Firefox and safari ! Pls checkout
https://stackoverflow.com/q/2643447/4672474

Answer (score -1):

This is basic structure from MDN and W3C

```html
<video width="600px" height="320px" class="video" controls poster="https://unsplash.it/598/320">
   <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm type=video/webm> 
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv type=video/ogg> 
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4 type=video/mp4>
<source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.3gp type=video/3gp>
</video>
```

Comment: I am not familiear with MDN nor W3C. I am a noob to video formating/codecs on websites. 

Could you help point out what my issue is? I am not sure why and not sure what to do.

Comment: It works in Chrome, and IE, but it does not work in firefox. I am not sure why it doesn't

Comment: This code work for you ? so you can follow the step, moreover I can provide you a link......

Comment: Almost all modern browser support HTML5 video tag
https://caniuse.com/#search=video